# zlib error -3 while reading content from server response

Tags: python, gzip, httpresponse, zlib, decoding

I'm getting a response from a server with the gzip encoding, 
but I can't figure how to decode it.

I tried using the zlib module but i get the error:
`zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check`

This is my request:

```
r = requests.post(url=url,headers=headers,auth=auth,data=data)
print r.status_code
print r.headers
print zlib.decompress(r.content)
```

The print i get is:

`200`
`{'Content-Length': '1232', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'X-Powered-By': 'PHP/5.5.38', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', ...`

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/testing.py", line 27, in <module>
    print zlib.decompress(r.content)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

Comment: `requests` should give you uncompressed content so you don't have to use zlib.

Comment: post `Content-Type`

Comment: The request: `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`.  The response: `'Content-Type': 'text/html'`

Comment: `requests` decompresses for you. `content` should already be decompressed and you can't decompress it again.

Comment: ok.. I'll take a look. I did get text, but some of it seemed compressed. You are probably right

Comment: first check `print r.content` and `print r.text`  - second should give already decoded using `utf-8`

Comment: @furas - good point! `r.text` returns decoded strings and `content` is just `bytes`.

Comment: "The gzip and deflate transfer-encodings are automatically decoded for you." from `requests` doc.

Comment: you can decompress `r.raw`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work to decompress r.raw

Comment: use `gzip.decompress(r.raw.read())`

Comment: address people with @

Answer (score 1):

Try `zlib.decompress(r.content, 31)` to request gzip decoding instead of zlib decoding.